# Image is not showing in javascript image slider

Tags: javascript, arrays, image-slider

I had created an image slider using HTML & JavaScript. The images are showing and working well when I use the slider with window.setInterval property and also with my next button but when I press my back button , the images are not found after the first image is shown. This means when I hit previous button the images are appearing in descending order one by one, but after first picture the **Javascript function is unable to loop images from last picture to the first picture.**
Inspecting the page following error is shown
undefined:1

```
   Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
```

Please Help!

following is my Javascript code

```
arr=["SMSlogo.jpg","spiderlogo.jpg","yt.jpg"];
        var value=0;
        slide();
        function slide(){
            document.getElementById("pic").src=arr[value];  
            value++;
            if(value==arr.length){
                value=0;
            }
        }
        window.setInterval(slide,3000);

        function back(){
            document.getElementById("pic").src=arr[value];
            value--;
            if(value==0){
                value=arr[arr.length-1];
            }
        }
        function next(){
            document.getElementById("pic").src=arr[value];
            value++;
            if(value==arr.length){
                value=0;
            }
        }
```

I'm expecting that my back button work properly and all images should be visible when I click the back button.

Comment: Please provide a proper [mre] of the issue.

Comment: `value=arr[arr.length-1];` should probably be `value=arr.length-1;`.

Comment: @connexo working.. but the slider is now looping only between 2nd and 3rd image.
I need the loop should be run between three/all images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't really make sense to do value = array.length -1 because the value = 2 is a valid index but it will get reset.
The problem here is that the back function will reset value to two if it's equal to zero while it's a valid index and won't reset it when it's equal to -1, an invalid index.

Basically replace the if(value == 0) to if(value < 0)